Solve the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(2-\cos(3x))}{1+x^2}dx$?
How to solve the following integral  $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(2-\cos(3x))}{1+x^2}dx?$$
Wolfram Mathematica shows the integral without logarithm,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2-\cos(3x)}{1+x^2}dx=\pi-\frac{\pi}{2e^3}.$$
It seems, it cannot be solved in closed form. Can we generate series solution or solution through special functions?

Can you solve the contour integral $$\oint_{C}\frac{e^{3 i z}}{1+z^2},$$ where $C$ is the union of the line segment ${\operatorname{Im}{z}=0,,0\leq \operatorname{Re}{z} \leq R}$, the circular arc ${|z|=R, 0\leq \arg{z}\leq \pi/2}$ and the line segment   $ { \operatorname{Re}{z}=0, , 0\leq \operatorname{Im}{z} \leq R}$

For reference, $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(1-2b \cos 2ax +b^{2})}{1+x^{2}} \ dx= \pi \log(1-be^{-2a})$, for $a>0$

@whatamidoing How you obtained this result? Can I use differentiation under integral sign method since we have introduced parameters?

@stephan One can use the real part of this $\log(1-e^{i  \theta})=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{i \theta })^{k}}{k} $

Too long for a comment
The comment by @whatamidoing solves the problem (we just have to choose the appropriate $a$ and $b$). If we want to solve the problem from scratch, we can do the following.
Denoting
$$I(a,b)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(b-\cos ax)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\big((c-d e^{iax})(c-d e^{-iax})\big)}{1+x^2}dx\,\,(b>1)$$
we find
$$c^2+d^2=b;\,cd=\frac12\,\Rightarrow\,c=\frac{\sqrt{b+1}+\sqrt{b-1}}2;\,d=\frac{\sqrt{b+1}-\sqrt{b-1}}2$$
Then
$$I(a,b)=\Re\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{b+1}+\sqrt{b-1}}2-\frac{\sqrt{b+1}-\sqrt{b-1}}2e^{iax}\right)}{1+x^2}dx\tag{1}$$
Closing the contour in the upper half-plane (where the logarithm does not have branch points), and the integrand has a single pole at $x=i$
$$\boxed{\,\,I(a,b)=\pi\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{b+1}+\sqrt{b-1}}2-\frac{\sqrt{b+1}-\sqrt{b-1}}2e^{-a}\right)\,\,}$$

Could you share what occurs for $b<1$? What do we do to handle such cases?

@Amrut Ayan, for $b\in[0;1]$ I got
$$I(a,b)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln|b-\cos ax|}{1+x^2}dx=\frac\pi2\ln\left(\frac{1-2be^{-a}+e^{-2a}}2\right)$$ what gives the correct answer at $b=0$ or $a=0$ ( https://themathematics.quora.com/How-can-i-solve-math-displaystyle-int-limits_0-infty-dfrac-ln-cos-2-x-x-2-dx-math-1 ). Bur WA (free option) refuses to provide a numeric check for the general case ($a,, b\neq 0$). Could you check the formula numerically? Thank you!

Annoying that WA does not give anything, i was thinking maybe using running a python script, so my integral was for $b=\frac{2}{3}, a=\sqrt2$, which spit out -0.5162949402908938 with an error of 0.002760273244777678, but I'm skeptical of this result, i hope you find time to check for this case $b=\frac{2}{3}, a=\sqrt2$, thanks!

@ Amrut Ayan, the answer is indeed correct (please see the strong proof in a new post). Numeric check with WA is, unfortunately, impossible

I read through the answer for the special case, It was really helpful, thank you sir!

@Amrut Ayan Thank your for the interesting question and high mark of my work :)

\begin{aligned}
&\Omega=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln (2-\cos 3 x)}{1+x^2} d x\\
&\text { Using : } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r^n \cos (n \theta)}{n}=-\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(1+r^2-2 r \cos \theta\right) \text { for }|r|<1\\
&\begin{gathered}
\ln \left(\frac{1+r^2}{2 r}-\cos \theta\right)=-\ln (2 r)-2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r^n \cos (n \theta)}{n} \\
\text { For } r=2-\sqrt{3} \text { and } \theta=3 x: \\
\ln (2-\cos 3 x)=-\ln (4-2 \sqrt{3})-2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2-\sqrt{3})^n \cos (3 n x)}{n} \\
\Omega=-2 \ln (\sqrt{3}-1) \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d x}{1+x^2}-2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2-\sqrt{3})^n}{n} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos (3 n x)}{1+x^2} d x \\
\Omega=-\pi \ln (\sqrt{3}-1)-\pi \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2-\sqrt{3})^n e^{-3 n}}{n} \\
\Omega=-\pi \ln (\sqrt{3}-1)-\pi \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{e^3}\right)^n}{n}=-\pi \ln (\sqrt{3}-1)+\pi \ln \left(1-\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{e^3}\right) \\
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln (2-\cos 3 x)}{1+x^2} d x=\pi \ln \left(e^3+\sqrt{3}-2\right)-\pi \ln (\sqrt{3}-1)-3 \pi
\end{gathered}
\end{aligned}

Let's consider separately an interesting case of $\,b\in[-1;1],\,a\geqslant0$
$$I(a,b)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln|b-\cos ax|}{1+x^2}dx=\frac a4\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln\big((b-\cos x)^2\big)}{x^2+a^2}dx$$
Denoting for a while $\,b=\cos c\,$ using the property $\,\cos c-\cos x=-2\sin\frac{c+x}2\sin\frac{c-x}2$, and also the symmetry with respect to $x\to-x$
$$I(a,b)=\frac a4\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln 4}{x^2+a^2}dx+\frac a2\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln\sin^2\frac{x-c}2}{x^2+a^2}dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi\ln2}2+a\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln\sin^2x}{(2x+c)^2+a^2}dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi\ln2}2+\frac a{4\pi^2}\int_0^\pi\ln\sin^2x\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac1{(\frac x\pi+\frac c{2\pi}+k)^2+\frac{a^2}{(2\pi)^2}}\right)dx$$
The sum $S$ in the parentheses can be evaluated in a standard way, considering the integral in the complex plane along a big contour $C$ which embraces the points $z=0,\pm1,\pm2...$
$$J=\oint_C\frac{\pi\cot\pi z}{(\frac x\pi+\frac c{2\pi}+z)^2+\frac{a^2}{(2\pi)^2}}dz\to 0=S\,\,+\underset{z=-\frac{c+2x}{2\pi}\pm i\frac a{2\pi}}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{\pi\cot\pi z}{(\frac x\pi+\frac c{2\pi}+z)^2+\frac{a^2}{(2\pi)^2}}$$
The residues evaluation is straightforward and gives
$$S=\frac{2\pi^2}a\Im\cot\big(x+\frac c2-i\frac a2\big)$$
Using this result, as well as $\,\displaystyle \sin^2x=\frac{(1-e^{2ix})(1-e^{-2ix})}4$
$$I(a,b)=\frac{\pi\ln2}2+\frac14\int_0^\pi\left(\ln\frac14+\ln(1-e^{2ix})+\ln(1-e^{-2ix})\right)\times$$
$$\times\left(\frac{e^{2ix}+e^{-ic-a}}{e^{2ix}-e^{-ic-a}}+\frac{e^{-2ix}+e^{ic-a}}{e^{-2ix}-e^{ic-a}}\right)dx=\frac{\pi\ln2}2+I_1+I_2+I_3\tag{0}$$
where
$$I_1=\frac14\ln\frac14\int_0^\pi\left(\frac{e^{2ix}+e^{-ic-a}}{e^{2ix}-e^{-ic-a}}+\frac{e^{-2ix}+e^{ic-a}}{e^{-2ix}-e^{ic-a}}\right)dx$$
$$=-\frac{\ln2}{4i}\oint_{|z|=1}\left(\frac{z+e^{-ic-a}}{z-e^{-ic-a}}-\frac{z+e^{-ic+a}}{z-e^{-ic+a}}\right)\frac{dz}z$$
$$=-\frac{\ln2}{4i}\,2\pi i\sum\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{z+e^{-ic-a}}{z-e^{-ic-a}}-\frac{z+e^{-ic+a}}{z-e^{-ic+a}}\right)\frac1z=-\pi\ln2\tag{1}$$
$$I_2=\frac14\int_0^\pi\ln(1-e^{2ix})\left(\frac{e^{2ix}+e^{-ic-a}}{e^{2ix}-e^{-ic-a}}+\frac{e^{-2ix}+e^{ic-a}}{e^{-2ix}-e^{ic-a}}\right)dx$$
Adding a small arch around $z=1$ (leaving the point outside the contour), using the fact that inside the contour $\ln(1-z)$ is a single-valued function and that the integral along this small arch tends to zero,
$$I_2=\frac1{8i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\ln(1-z)}z \left(\frac{z+e^{-ic-a}}{z-e^{-ic-a}}-\frac{z+e^{-ic+a}}{z-e^{-ic+a}}\right)dz$$
$$=\frac\pi2\ln(1-e^{-ic-a})\tag{2}$$
In the same way,
$$I_3=\frac\pi2\ln(1-e^{ic-a})\tag{3}$$
Putting (1), (2) and (3) into (0) and remembering that $b=\cos c$,
$$I(a,b)=\frac{\pi\ln2}2-\pi\ln2+\frac\pi2\ln(1-e^{-ic-a})+\frac\pi2\ln(1-e^{ic-a})$$
$$=-\frac{\pi\ln2}2+\frac\pi2\ln(1-2\cos c\,e^{-a}+e^{-2a})$$
$$\boxed{\,\,I(a,b)=\frac\pi2\ln\frac{1-2be^{-a}+e^{-2a}}2\,\,}$$
Just two comments to add:
I did not find the integral in the list of integrals by I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik, though the easier integrals are presented (for example, FI II 718a, GW (338)(28a,b) p.569 )
This answer can be straightforwardly obtained from the formula (1) in the previous post (above), if we just take $\sqrt{b-1}=i\sqrt{1-b}$
